# Why I can't use append() to add a variable to a string?

Tags: c++, append, push-back

I have a piece of code:

```
char temp = word[0];
word.erase(0, 1);
word.append(temp);     //word.push_back(temp); is fine
```

I got an error:
error: no matching member function for call to 'append'

My question is why I can't use append() here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the type of `word`? How is it declared?

Comment: Hi Enlico, thanks for asking. word is a string
    stringstream ss(sentence);
    string word;
     while(ss >> word){}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that `word` is a `std::string`.

If you look at the documentation for [`std::basic_string::append()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append), you'll see that it has a bunch of overloads, but all of them are for strings or repeated characters. There simply is not any overload that accepts a single character.

That's all there is to it.

[`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) appends single characters, [`append()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) appends *strings* of characters. In your example, `temp` is a single character, so of the two function you are inquiring about, only `push_back()` is available.

Alternatively, `std::string` provides `operator+=()`, which works in both cases. So you could also do:

```
word += temp;
```

Comment: "*In your example, `temp` is a single character, so only `push_back()` is available.*" - there is also [`string::operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D), which accepts both single chars and strings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I should indeed have mentioned that I was addressing OP's question quite literally. Corrected.